# Ubuntu 14.04 login screen loop

Tags: 14.04

When I try to login in Ubuntu, It login and freeze in desktop screen. When I try to solve this I refer [this link](http://jiakaizhang.com/fix-frozen-after-login-in-ubuntu-14-04/), my problem is solved with small trouble.After this I restart and login into Ubuntu it login and shows same login screen. So I search something about "login loop" I referred [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LvqvOVn5drs). I installed unity desktop and reboot and then restarted my ubuntu still my problem is not solved. I hope lot of you faced this problem if yours is solved. Please share your solutions with me to retrieve my ubuntu OS.

Thanks,
Ami

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this when the root/home partition is 100% full. To check that you can type:

```
ctrl-alt-f1
```

at the login screen (which drops you to a shell) and then login as normal. After you have logged in you can type:

```
df -h
```

which will report your disk usage.

Comment: to go back to the graphical login screen you need to type `ctrl-alt-f7`

Comment: I have checked all those thinks.. still I cant login

Comment: @Ami can you log in on the `ctrl-alt-f1` screen?

Comment: To terminal right.. Yes I can and I update it and then I install unity desktop. Nothing happening :(